# How to specify multiple condition in Join statement rather than in Where block in NHibernate QueryOver

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, queryover

The following QueryOver generates the Subquery in the Where block but i was rather looking for the way to specify that condition on the join statement

```
var productsWithLatestComments = _sessionHelper.GetSession().QueryOver(() => p)
                .Left.JoinAlias(() => p.Comments, () => cm)
                .WithSubquery.Where(() => cm.CommentDate == QueryOver.Of<Comment>()
                    .Where(c => c.Product.Id == p.Id)
                    .SelectList(list => list.SelectMax(c => c.CommentDate)).As<DateTime>())
                .Where(() => p.Status != "NOT SOLD" )
                .SelectList(list => list ....GET THE LIST OF COLS.........
```

This GENERATES something like

```
SELECT this_.id as y0_, ......... FROM product this_ 
left outer join comment cn1_ on this_.id=cn1_.product_id 
WHERE cn1_.comment_date = (SELECT max(this_0_.created_date) as y0_ FROM comment this_0_ WHERE this_0_.product_id = this_.id) and (not (this_.status = ?p0);?p0 = 'Sold Out'' [Type: String (18)]
```

But i was looking for

```
SELECT this_.id as y0_, ......... FROM product this_ 
left outer join comment cn1_ on this_.id=cn1_.product_id and cn1_.comment_date = (SELECT max(this_0_.created_date) as y0_ FROM comment this_0_ WHERE this_0_.product_id = this_.id)
WHERE (not (this_.status = ?p0);?p0 = 'Sold Out'' [Type: String (18)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it with some changes in the QueryOver by specifying the subquery inside the join alias rather than inside .WithSubquery

```
var productsWithLatestComments = _sessionHelper.GetSession().QueryOver(() => p)
                .JoinAlias(() => p.Comments, () => cm, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Subqueries.Where(() => cm.CommentDate == QueryOver.Of<Comment>()
                    .Where(c => c.Product.Id == p.Id)
                    .SelectList(list => list.SelectMax(c => c.CommentDate)).As<DateTime>()))
                .Where(() => p.Status != "NOT SOLD" )
                .SelectList(list => list ....GET THE LIST OF COLS.........
```